# Which Java client to use for calculating HTTP performance metrics like TCP connection time, Time to first byte, TLS handshake time etc

Tags: java, okhttp, asynchttpclient, java-http-client

I am looking for a Java HTTP Async client which can be used to get performance metrics like TCP connection time, Time to first byte, TLS handshake time for an endpoint.

I looked into latest [java.net.http](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/module-summary.html) module but it does not seem to have any such listeners. In fact, only async java client i found which seems to be carrying these listeners is [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client). However, problem is that it is an open source project and currently does not have any active maintainer. It might be a dead project already and in the long run might not be sustainable?

What is the recommended option for this use case in java?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the tags for your question so I assume you've considered OkHttp. It has an events API that's usable for metrics.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/events/

Comment: I somehow missed this client. Thanks a lot.